# Is there an English phrase aligning with "甘为人梯" in Chinese?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

In China, normal school students are taught to have the spirit of sacrificing themselves for the improvement of their students. Instead of concerning the threads(ladder-climbing) from who they are teaching they should be willing to let their students be better or higher in status than themselves.

This, in Chinese, is called the spirit of "甘为人梯" which literally means being ready to be the ladder for others(or climbers).

Which phrase or saying can it align with if there is possibly one?

Comment: I'm a little confused... "students are taught to have the spirt of sacrficeing themselves for the improvement of their students" Do students have students?  Do you mean "teachers are taught...".

Comment: @JamesK it likely “students (at universities) studying to become teachers (at regular schools)”

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why it is a "sacrifice"  For a teacher, if their student achieves success, that is a success for the teacher too.  The student's success doesn't detract from the teacher, it only adds to it.

Comment: True, if a teacher's jealous of his student then he's not meant to be called 'a teacher'

Comment: I don't think it's weird to encourage healthy attitudes in people - especially teachers, who are specifically in a situation where they try to raise people up to be better than them. We're only human, we all have our own insecurities and egos, so encouraging people to surmount that and be better is a good and normal thing to do! The OP's just asking how other places encourage that same kind of personal philosophy and social responsibility - I can't think of any specific phrases or proverbs about lifting up others though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lend a helping hand**

- The phrase "lend a helping hand" or "extend a helping hand" is well known.  You could say "Be ready to lend a helping hand" or "Extend a helping hand to others".

**Pay it forward**

- An interesting and snappy expression that has become popular in recent years, "Pay it forward" refers to the notion that instead of paying back the person who helped you, you "pay it forward" by helping other people.

**The ladder**

- Ladder metaphors are sometimes used in English too.  The economist Ha-Joon Chang has written a book about the opposite phenomenon ("Kicking Away The Ladder": he refers to the idea that developed countries aren't helping developing countries to succeed).
- The following phrase is slightly wordy, and not well known, but gets across the idea well in good English.  It is attributed to the author Frank Sonnenberg: "As you climb your ladder of success, reach down and pull others along with you."
- A similar phrase used by Harmony Spiritual Center in the US is: "Share the knowledge you have, help someone up the ladder."
- The organisation PAWH (Pan African Women in Health) uses this expression: "When a sister goes to the top, she must let down the ladder for others to climb up too."

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any specific phrases or proverbs, but I wanted to post an answer just to point something out.

I feel like the general idea of "don't worry about your personal status, use it to help others to do better than you" won't appear in too many quotes or proverbs or whatever. That's just because "don't worry about your personal status" seems a little too honest, acknowledging some possible jealousy or the fact you might not put your students ahead of your own ego. If people need to be told not to do this, they might have a problem! So I could see that kind of maxim being unpopular, because people don't like being reminded that they're flawed and need to work at doing the right thing, if that makes sense.

I feel like there are probably lots of quotes and proverbs that might fit - things that talk about raising others, doing your best for them so they can have a better life, doing things for others that you won't personally benefit from, socially conscious ideas like "it takes a vilage to raise a child"... I just can't think of any offhand. Others might though!